# how to prevent youtube player from Keypressing ( rewind , forward or pause the video )?

Tags: javascript, youtube, dom-events

I'm trying to create a **youtube Extension** ( not the youtube api ) and I require to prevent all the `keypress` events from happening during the `playback`

> **for example** : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=(ANY_VIDEO )

so far I've tried the following :

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => console.log(e));
```

just to get some clues which kinda helped

then I've tried :

```
document.removeEventListener('keydown');
```

didnt work ,it has removed the `keydown` from the entire dom but not from the player for example i couldn't refresh the page using `f5`

as i can see on console under target i can see `div` of `id = movie_player` so i assumed that this is what I should remove the event from , but I've no clue what the handler of the function is , it's really hard to inspect it .

I can see from googleing that some other extention have had this feature in it but it  was way more complicated that youtube itself .
[How to disable keyboard shortcuts using - uBlockOrigin Extension](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/ae3vja/how_to_disable_keyboard_shortcuts/)

Comment: To remove an event listener, you need to find what pre-defined function was used to add an event listener originally. (`document.removeEventListener('keydown', myEventHandler);`). I would recommend investigating, in your browser debug panel, exactly where and what the YouTube page's DOM handlers are. https://i.imgur.com/gX8MDCw.png (Chrome: in the Sources tab, on the bottom, under Global Listeners)

Comment: @Drakinite thank you but what am i suppose to do with this ???
https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_watch_v2-vflteBBN-/desktop_polymer_sel_auto_svg_watch_v2.js

Comment: Load it into an IDE, do an auto-format, and see if you can examine vaguely how the code functions. I take it that you've already looked up how to do wjat you're looking for, and haven't been able to find a solution from your research?

Answer (score 0):

controls=0 disables the controls of youtube and

playinfo=0 to disable the information about video.

Also disablekb=1 will disable the keyboard controls while playing. The sample url for reference is

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/_MNvO7Z26YY?enablejsapi=1&controls=0&playinfo=0&disablekb=1
```

Sample:

`http://jsfiddle.net/krifriends4ever/58fpyswr/3/`